# laravel form model binding and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am having an issue while binding from data with my model. When I load the edit page for editing a resource, I can see the input value in the input but it disappears asap since its binded to the vuejs.

Here is my vuejs data

```
data: {
        form: new Form({
            title: '',
            language: [],
            poster: ''
        })
    },
```

and my inputs are like this

```
{!! Form::model($movie, ['class' => 'form-horizontal', '@submit.prevent' => 'form.updateMovie', 'id' => 'update-movie-form', 'files' => true, '@keydown' => 'form.errors.clear($event.target.name)']) !!}
....
{!! Form::text('title', 'movie title', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'title', 'v-model' => 'form.title']) !!}
....
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

How I can get around this issue?

Comment: Is your vue code in the blade file or a js file? If a js file are you compiling it down using webpack?

Comment: @RossWilson its in js file.

Comment: yup, compiling it using webpack

Comment: Cool, cool. Are you still using Laravel collective so the form degrades gracefully if javascript isn't enabled?

Comment: haha @RossWilson what should I do then, I am not that experienced with vuejs

Comment: If you're not bothered if javascript is disabled then you could create a component specifically for this form. You would just need to pass `$model` in as a prop and assign the values to the form object.

Comment: @RossWilson any resource on the internet that you can refer?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and adding the entire form from your blade file and your `Vue` object?

Comment: ...or you could just have a look at https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same issue today.

> The Vue.js version 1 allows us to provide initial values to the `v-model` via value attribute, but this functionality was deprecated on the version 2.0.
>
> Migration guide says:
>
> `v-model` no longer cares about the initial value of an inline value attribute. For predictability, it will instead always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth.

Credit where credit due: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-data-scooper

The author of that plugin (and quote) identifies a change in Vue.js, and wrote the `vue-data-scooper` plugin as a work-around (to restore the former functionality).

I'm now using the plugin myself (following the instructions on the above link) and can confirm it "resolves" the issue you're seeing.

---

I don't wish to *duplicate* the existing instructions found in the plugin's documentation, but I didn't find they aligned precisely with the Laravel installation I was using (v5.4).

Specifically I installed the plugin...

```
npm install vue-data-scooper
```

...then patched my `app.js` (which is extremely minimal in my case)...

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueDataScooper from "vue-data-scooper"
Vue.use(VueDataScooper);
```

...and dropped the `data: {...}` declaration from my `new Vue(...)` declarations (allowing the plugin to sort it out using initial data).

Comment: Added specific instructions that I followed for a very javascript-light and "as ships" Laravel 5.4 installation.  I'm an AngularJS guy, not Vue - so I my "integration" may be less than ideal...